# how to create 100% vertical line in css

Tags: html, css

I want to create a vertical line that cover whole page like this

[image]

here is my code

```
#menu
{
border-left: 1px solid black;
height: 100%;
}
```

result show like this
[image]

Comment: `height: 100%` makes it the height of its parent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As bookcasey said, `height: 100%;` will only make the DIV 100% of its parent. For this reason you will need to make `html, body {height: 100%; min-height: 100%}` as stated by Marko, but also, make the same change on every parent DIV of `#menu`.

Because you have a bottom border, then apply the right border to the parent DIV at `height: 100%;` and apply the bottom-border to your `#menu` at whatever height you want the bottom border to show up.

Answer (score 28):

Use an absolutely positioned pseudo element:

```
ul:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ckFvs)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I apply your code. But If my menu item list height larger then 100% then border don't show on the bottom. Thanks

Comment: For anyone else who read this, To get the proper heights (since using `position:absolute`), sometimes you must explicitly define `position:relative` on the containing element of (in this case, `ul`) your :before/:after selector element, otherwise the height will likely be larger/longer, because it's finding the height of some farther up parent element that has defined a position.

Answer (score 6):

There are at least two ways to solve this.

**Solution 1:**

If you are okay with using an absolutely positioned element, you can use the `top` and `bottom` properties instead of `height`. By setting both `top` and `bottom` to `0` you force the element into taking up full height.

```
#menu
{
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/twkgR/)**

**Solution 2:**

Another way would be to force the HTML and BODY elements into a 100% height, to give room for a menu with 100% height:

```
body, html { height: 100%; }
#menu
{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/twkgR/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your response. I apply your code. But If my menu item list height larger then 100% then border don't show on the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

100% height refers to the height of the parent container. In order for your div to go full height of the body you have to set this:

```
html, body {height: 100%; min-height: 100%}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use this css positioning for most of my vertical elements:

```
<div class="vertical-line" style="height: 250px;
width: 1px;
background-color: #81F781;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: -100px;
postion: absolute;
border-radius: 2px;">
</div>
```

Change the height and width to fit the page, or to make a horizontal line swap the height to width:

```
<div class="vertical-line" style="height: 250px;
width: 1px;

<div class="vertical-line" style="width: 250px;
height: 1px;
```

instead of a standard html line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Welcome</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .head1 {
        width:300px;
        border-right:1px solid #333;
        float:left;
        height:500px;
    }
   .head2 {
       float:left;
       padding-left:100PX;
       padding-top:10PX;
   }
</style>
<body>
   <h1 class="head1">Ramya</h1>
   <h2 class="head2">Reddy</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used `min-height: 100vh;` with great success on some of my projects. [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/uch0g0ss/).

Answer (score 0):

When I tested this, I tried using the position property and it worked perfectly.

HTML

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="body">
 //add content here
 </body>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
 position: relative;
}

.body{
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
}
```